# An exception happened when I add SavedStateHandle in my viewmodel's constructor

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel

I need to add SavedStateHandle in my ViewModel's constructor but when I add it, I have an exception and I don't find the solution. If I remove it, the screen is displayed without error. I followed the tutorial on the Android website : https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation?hl=fr#retrieving-complex-data .
Btw, I don't use Hilt and I don't want like the tutorial.
I searched on google to find a solution but I didn't see anyone with the same problem. I think it's a stupid mistake but I don't see.

The line that is problematic in the viewModel constructor:
`savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle,`

Exception :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.loreal.swatchbook, PID: 29666
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.*.*.*.TestViewModel
.....
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: class com.*.*.*.TestViewModel.<init> []
```

My route :

```
composable(
            route = ApplicationScreen.Test.route,
            arguments = listOf(
                navArgument(name = navigationInputArgument) {
                    type = NavType.StringType
                },
            )
        ) {
            TestScreen(
                navigator = navigator
            )
        }
```

Screen constructor :

```
@Composable
fun TestScreen(
    navigator: Navigator<ApplicationScreen>,
    viewModel: TestViewModel = viewModel(),
) {
```

And ViewModel constructor :

```
class TestViewModel(
    savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle,
    private val translations: TestTranslations = TestTranslations()
) : ViewModel() {
```